# Set variable for R.drawable

Tags: android, google-maps, android-drawable

At the moment I set a marker image for google maps on android like this:

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mon1))
```

Where `mon1` is the name of the corresponding to a image called `mon1.png` in drawable folder.

How can I do it like this:

```
 String imagename="blablaimage";

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.imagename))
```

Comment: why you want to do it this way? if the drawables are in your project, you know the resource identifier....can you please explain the reason for better understanding?

Comment: I have more than one marker, based on the current location. The name of the image that should be used is stored in a database. Thats why i need a "dynamic" image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you suggested.

Instead, a possible workaround might be to use the following function:

```
public int getDrawableId(String name){
        try {
            Field fld = R.drawable.class.getField(name);
            return fld.getInt(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

and use like:

```
 String imagename="blablaimage";

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getDrawableId(imagename)));
```

Comment: How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

If you click over `R.drawable.mon1`, you'll find an int declared with the name mon1 in R.java class. Everything resides in R class is basically an int. That said, you can't declare variable `imagename` as String to begin with. It must be int.

Everything generates in R.java class is auto generated by Android itself. Once you put some resources in appropriate directory, R.java generates corresponding resource int within so that it can be invoked from Java-end.

Bottom line, if you have an image called blablaimage somewhere in your drawable, you can (at best) do this,

```
int imagename= R.drawable.blablaimage;

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(imagename))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using `Resources.getIdentifier`:

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(
   context.getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", "com.mypackage.myapp"); 
));
```